# How to change centered slide by clicking on desired slide in swiper.js?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I use swiper in centeredSlides mode and loop option is true. I want to when I click on a slide, that slide set as centered slide in swiper carousel. Swiper give me clicked slide index, but how to use it for change the centered slide?

These are my options:

```
  slidesPerView: 4.5,
  spaceBetween: 20,
  updateOnWindowResize: true,
  loop: true,
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  centeredSlidesBounds: true,
  initialSlide: 0,
  on: {
    click() {
      console.log(this.clickedIndex);
    },
  },
```

Comment: Are you able to create a fiddle or working example of this, with the HTML and CSS? Otherwise any solution may not look like what you're seeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 4.5,
  spaceBetween: 20,
  updateOnWindowResize: true,
  loop: true,
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  centeredSlidesBounds: true,
  initialSlide: 0,
  on: {
    click() {
        console.log('index', this.clickedIndex);
        mySwiper.slideTo(this.clickedIndex);    
    },
  },
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Terrafire123/pen/gOwbjMy

Answer (score 4):

Just set `slideToClickedSlide` to `true` and click on any slide will produce transition to this slide